# postgresql foreign key constraints to prevent duplicates

Tags: postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, duplicates

I am using a trigger function to write data into a new table in Postgresql 9.1. Everything is now working correctly but I am getting duplicates. Can I use foreign key constraints to prevent duplicates from being produced? I haven`t used foreign key constraints before.

Here is the table structure

```
DROP TABLE "obx" CASCADE;
   CREATE TABLE "obx" (
    "obxID" serial primary key,
    "Pid" varchar,
    "Sid" varchar,
    "SidOrig" varchar,
    "Parameter" varchar,
    "Result" varchar,
    "ResultOrig" varchar,
    "Units" varchar,
    "RefRange" varchar,
    "Flag" varchar,
    "FlagOrig" varchar,
    "OperatorID" varchar,
    "ObsTime" char(14),
    "MsgTime" char(14),
    "UnixTime" int4,
    "Analyzer" varchar,
    "Segment" varchar
    );

DROP TABLE "testcode" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE "testcode" (
    "TcodeID" serial primary key,
    "Analyzer" varchar,
    "Parameter" varchar,
    "TestName" varchar,
    "ShortTestName" varchar,
    "TestID" int4
    ) ;
DROP TABLE "finaldata" CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE "finaldata" (
    "FdataID" serial primary key,
    "Pid" varchar,
    "Sid" varchar,
    "SidOrig" varchar,
    "Parameter" varchar,
    "Result" varchar,
    "ResultOrig" varchar,
    "Units" varchar,
    "OperatorID" varchar,
    "ObsTime" varchar,
    "MsgTime" varchar,
    "Analyzer" varchar,
    "TestName" varchar,
    "ShortTestName" varchar,
    "TestID" varchar,
    "XYchar1" varchar,
    "XYchar2" varchar,
    "XYchar3" varchar,
    "XYint1" int4,
    "XYint2" int4,
    "XYint3" int4,
    "XYGuid" uuid
    ) ;
```

And the trigger function:

```
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO finaldata ("Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter", "Result", "ResultOrig", "Units"
        , "OperatorID", "ObsTime", "MsgTime", "Analyzer", "TestName", "ShortTestName", "TestID")
      SELECT ob."Pid", ob."Sid", ob."SidOrig", ob."Parameter", ob."Result", ob."ResultOrig", ob."Units"
        , ob."OperatorID", ob."ObsTime", ob."MsgTime", ob."Analyzer"
        , tc."TestName", tc."ShortTestName", tc."TestID"
      FROM obx ob
      JOIN testcode tc ON ob."Parameter" = tc."Parameter"
            WHERE ob."Sid" = NEW."Sid"
            AND ob."ObsTime" = NEW."ObsTime"
            AND ob."Parameter" = NEW."Parameter"
            AND ob."Analyzer" = NEW."Analyzer"
      AND tc."TestID" IS NOT NULL
           ;
      RETURN NEW;
  END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use foreign key constraints to prevent duplicates from being produced?

**About duplicates**

No, you use either `PRIMARY KEY` or `NOT NULL UNIQUE` to prevent duplicates. This declaration

```
CREATE TABLE "finaldata" (
    "FdataID" serial primary key,
```

guarantees that each row will be unique, but it doesn't guarantee that the thing the row represents--which is what database designers are interested in--will be unique. Let me give you a smaller example.

```
create table person (
  person_id serial primary key,
  full_name varchar(35) not null
);

insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');
insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');
insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');
insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');
insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');

select * from person;
--
1   Mendez, Cathy
2   Mendez, Cathy
3   Mendez, Cathy
4   Mendez, Cathy
5   Mendez, Cathy
```

The serial ID number makes each *row* unique, but it doesn't do anything for the thing the row represents.  If I did this

```
delete from person;
alter table person
add constraint person_uniq unique (full_name);
```

then this insert will succeed,

```
insert into person (full_name) values ('Mendez, Cathy');
```

but running it a second time will fail with this error.

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "person_uniq"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (full_name)=(Mendez, Cathy) already exists.
```

So to prevent duplicates in the table finaldata, you need a UNIQUE constraint on some subset of the columns.

My guess--and it's just a guess--is that you need at least {"Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter"}.

**About foreign keys**

Foreign keys guarantee that the values you put in one set of columns already exist *in a different table*.

For example, the values in the column finaldata.pid probably already exist in another table. If the set of values in the finaldata columns {"Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter"} are supposed to already exist in the table obx, then a foreign key constraint like this will prevent meaningless data from finding its way into those finaldata columns.

```
constraint finaldata_fk1
foreign key ("Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter")
  references obx ("Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter")
```

You might also need `on delete cascade`, `on update cascade`, or some other referential action.

A foreign key will only work if there's a unique constraint on the referenced columns. You don't have one of those yet. You'd need a unique constraint on the obx columns {"Pid", "Sid", "SidOrig", "Parameter"} for that specific foreign key constraint to work.

Comment: The OP has asked this question two times before. The underlying problem is that his data model is ill defined: the finaldata table duplicates most of the data of obx (where only a reference to the primary key would suffice) Even the "parameter" field is not part of the candidate key, since it is fully functionally dependent on PK(obx) -> parameter. A unique FK (obx.ObxId would suffice) I rest my case.

Comment: I did ask a related question but that was about triggers. The trigger part is now working. The finaldata table is a duplicate of a lot of the information but another system connects to the DB and reads the data from the finaldata table via ODBC. This is why it is setup as it is. There are only a few duplicates now and I`m sure the  unique constraint and foreign keys will sort out the rest. Thanks

Comment: The unique constraint does successfully block the duplicates. Unfortunately it also blocks wanted records. The machine sends records in batches - eg there may be 10 records. 6 are wanted and the trigger filters them correctly - except that some duplicates (usually 1 or 2) are produced. I`ll now try to use a trigger on a trigger and see if this works. Thanks for the clear explanation and @wildplasser for the earlier help on triggers.

Comment: Again: the real problem is not in "one or two duplicates are generated by the trigger functions", but in the *lack of a data model*. All three tables appear to have surrogate keys as PK, but *lack a solid real PK*. The lack of 1-3 FKs makes the mess complete. Even if finaldata is supposed to be a 1->1 copy of obx (given the parameter is present in testcode), you *need* the key constraints. The surrogate keys mean nothing.

Comment: @user1044111: You said, "The unique constraint does successfully block the duplicates. Unfortunately it also blocks wanted records." That means you defined the unique constraint incorrectly.